# DllNotFoundException occurs when building Unity project on iOS

Tags: c#, xcode, unity-game-engine, bind

## What I want to do

- I want to use dylib (c header library) from iOS

## Current Issues

- unity build and xcode build are complete.
- Calling dylib functions in the simulator raises `DllNotFoundException`

## What I did.

- I put `dylib` in `Assets/Plugins/iOS`.
- In the Wrapper, set `DLLImport=[libname]`.
  The reason it is not `__Internal` is because it is a `dylib` and therefore not a static library.